# UIWebView : Change page number position for pdf file in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm opening a pdf file with UIWebView and once i'm starting to scroll down it shows be the page number box in left corner.I want to change position of page number to bottom of pdf page. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: you can't do that. If you want to do a custom PDF viewer, take a look at Apple's ZoomingPDFViewer example in the iOS Developer Library.

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(0,100);"];
```

instead of `100`, the position of the page to be given.

Comment: Would be nice to tell why the -1? The snippet I provided is not working?